# sql update query not updating database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, ado.net

Im writing an application that updates a database that ive created. The application has a datagridview on it which displays the data from the database. 
Something very weird is going on with my app.

Here is the code that updates the database

```
string updateCommandString = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]=@checkedDate WHERE      ID = @id"; 
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        updateCommand.Connection = conn;
        updateCommand.CommandText = updateCommandString;
        updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedDate", 
            this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.roomID);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch(OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run that code, close out off the app, and run the app again, the changed are correctly displayed in my datagridview that is connected to the database, but when i look at the actual database, nothing has changed at all. I dont know why this is happening.

My sql update updates the database, which is connected to the datagrid view. Sow HOW is the datagrid view displaying the correct data but not the database itself.

edit:
I have had no sort of experience with sql before.

edit:
transaction code:

```
 string updateCommandString = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]=@checkedDate WHERE ID = @id"; 
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb"))
                        {
                            OleDbTransaction transaction = null;
                         using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand())
                             {

                                    updateCommand.Connection = conn;
                                    updateCommand.Transaction = transaction;    
                                    updateCommand.CommandText = updateCommandString;
                                    updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedDate", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
                                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.roomID);
                            try
                            {
                                conn.Open();
                                transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                transaction.Commit();

                                conn.Close();
                                conn.Dispose();
                            }
                            catch(OleDbException ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()` is necessary. Converting DateTime to string is culture specific.

Comment: why use conn.Dispose? when you use "Using" objects atomatically Dispose

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting and exception within but it's not an OldDbException? Do you find anything if you expand the catch to 'Exception'?

Comment: i just cant think of any way the datagrid displays the newly updated data and not the database if the datagrid gets its data from the database

Comment: @Kamil ok that fixed one issue i was trying to solve, which is updating the datagrid view after i submit the new dates. But it still doesnt update the actual database

Comment: also under my data connections the database name has a red x next to it...that cant be good right?

Comment: Are you REALLY sure that the file you are opening is the same file, that your application connects? Have you searched for copies of that file in project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. Your application may connect to copy of database file. Search your project directory for copies of database (.accdb extension?)
2. Maybe David S is right, but you have to commit changes on database ([OleDbTransaction help at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit.aspx)). Changing isolation settings to READ UNCOMMITTED is inelegant approach to problem.

Comment: I added an additional note to my answer.  Yes; in general, don't change to READ UNCOMMITTED.  Either commit the transaction in your app, or if you want to inspect a transaction/data without committing during testing, then temporarily change the level.  I have had occasion where I wanted to do this while trying to debug a problem, etc.  But, not something I would usually go to production with.  I agree with your assertion that it is an "inelegant" approach.

Comment: ahh i see. i didnt call a commit() method. but what would I call the method on?

Comment: @Stonep123 you have to create transaction object. Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit.aspx

Let us know if this will work.

Comment: posted edit to question with the new transaction code...the executenonquery is throwing an exeption

Comment: Put "updateCommand.Transaction = transaction";  after you create object transaction. I mean put it after "transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();", in that "try" block.

Comment: ok the code runs now without exception..however when i open the database i still see no changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17357/discussion-between-kamil-and-stonep123)

Comment: ive searched the solution and only have one database with a .accdb ending

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you *may* have a transaction isolation issue to me. If you are unfamiliar with this topic, suggest you google & read the docs.  I believe READ COMMITTED is the default ... Setting it to READ UNCOMMITTED probably fixes issue for you not being able to see the updates.  But,  this is not really a recommended approach.  In general, you will just want to make sure that all of your transactions are committed to the database before trying to inspect the information.

Additional note: I've had need from time to time during testing an application to want to be able to query the db from a SQL tool outside of my application to check on something.  However, in almost 15 years of developing db applications, I've never had need to set this to READ UNCOMMITTED for production.  I would be very cautious about going to production on anything other than READ COMMITTED.  I'm not saying there is never a case where you would need to want that, but it's not the norm (IMHO).